# How do I Track Down a File's Location from Unity Search?

Tags: unity, 13.10, search, .desktop

So my problem is that, while installing Eclipse, I created some desktop files in different locations, installing them all (I was trying to solve a bug, hence the need for repeatedly installing .desktop files. Somewhere along the line I must have created one in an alternate directory).

But anyways, my dilemma now is that when I search "Eclipse" from Unity Search I get two icons in the results. One is the one I wanted to use (i.e. the .desktop file with the correct settings, arguments), and the other is absolutely useless. However for the life of me, I can't figure out where the useless entry is located. I've tried just using Nautilus's search to find .desktop files, but it only gives me the correct .desktop file. I have no idea where the .desktop with the incorrect information is located; the only way I can locate it is through the search bar of Unity.

I'm reasonably sure that I've created a soft link to it in my bin; not sure though. Anyways, my question here is whether there's some way to locate files from Unity search. Dragging the result into Terminal doesnt seem to work, and the search feature is supremely unhelpful concerning file paths.

[Subquestion with no real answer]: I'm also looking for a better desktop environment. I really hate having to make .desktop files just to get a program into the Unity toolbar, and long for just being able to drag-and-drop a program in like Windows. Any help here?

Anyways, thanks!